# Backbone.js: retrieving a collection from the server in PHP

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having a look at Backbone.js, but I'm stuck. The code until now is as simple as is possible, but I seem not to get it. I use Firebug and this.moments in the render of MomentsView is an object, but all the methods from a collection don't work (ie this.moments.get(1) doesn't work).

The code:

```
var Moment = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var Moments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Moment,
    url: 'moments',
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

var MomentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        this.moments = new Moments();
    },
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.moments, function(moment) {
            console.log(moment.get('id'));
        });

        return this;
    }
})

var momentsview = new MomentsView();
momentsview.render();
```

The (dummy) response from te server:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"this is the moment","description":"another descr","day":"12"},{"id":"2","title":"this is the mament","description":"onother dascr","day":"14"}]
```

The object has two models according to the DOM in Firebug, but the methods do not work. Does anybode have an idea how to get the collection to work in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're fetching the data asynchronously when you initialize the `MomentsView` view, but you're calling `momentsview.render()` synchronously, right away. The data you're expecting hasn't come back from the server yet, so you'll run into problems. I believe this will work if you call render in a callback to be executed once `fetch()` is complete.

Also, I don't think you can call `_.each(this.moments)` - to iterate over a collection, use `this.moments.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '()' when instantiate the collection.

```
this.moments = new Moments;
```

Also, as it's an asynchronous call, bind the collection's 'change' event with the rendering.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't think that should make any difference - it's just two syntax variations.

Comment: I agree... but I had problem because of that.